# ProgressDialog Background Activity Fade Out Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, progressdialog

I am building a custom ProgressDialog and would like for the background Activity to fade faster and darker than default.  The only problem is I do not know where to look for the animation that handles the fading for a ProgressDialog.  I have worked my way upstream from ProgressDialog -> AlertDialog -> Dialog but dont see anything in the java that looks useful.  I am assuming there is an animation .xml file that controls it, so I am looking for that file, and how the calling program makes use of it.

Just to be a little more clear, the animation I am refering to is when a ProgressDialog pops up, the previously active activity fades to dark.  I want to gain control of that animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways I know of to alter the background dimming are via the **android:backgroundDimEnabled** and **android:backgroundDimAmount** settings (to completely turn on/off the background dimming and to control the amount of background dimming, respectively)

To alter these values, create (or edit) your **res/values/styles.xml** file with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.ControlledDim" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.2</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And apply that theme in the activity's manifest by setting the theme to

**@style/Theme.ControlledDim**

This may not offer as much control as you'd like but is hopefully a step in the right direction

(The default setting for **android:backgroundDimAmount** is 0.6)

Comment: Good answer, but how about a way to do this completely programmatically, like some method call?